# Implement numpy-like slicing in an object

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing a sparse matrix library (why is another story...)

So far I have the base class with operator overload for +, -, *, etc...

The minimal code would be something like this:

```
class SpMat:
    """
    Matrix in compressed-column or triplet form.
    """
    def __init__(self, m=0, n=0):
        """
        @param m: number of rows
        @param n: number of columns
        """

        # number of rows
        self.m = m

        # number of columns
        self.n = n

        self.data = [[0 for x in range(self.n)] for y in range(self.m)]

    def [i, j]:  # this is what I want to implement

        if isinstance(i, int) and isinstance(j, int):
            return self.data[i][j]
        elif isinstance(i, int) and j = :
            return "the row i"  # will implement it
        elif isinstance(j, int) and i = :
            return "the column j"  # will implement it
```

So in the sample code I want to implement something like `def [i, j]` to get and set values, but I have no clue how to tell python that when I write `myobject[a, b]` I want to get the values at the coordinates a, b and when I write `myobject[a, b]= some_value` I want to set the value at the coordinates a, b.

Comment: I believe you can find an answer here https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__ by yourself :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `__getitem__` method of your class.

```
class SpMat:
    """
    Matrix in compressed-column or triplet form.
    """
    def __init__(self, m=0, n=0):
        """
        @param m: number of rows
        @param n: number of columns
        """

        # number of rows
        self.m = m

        # number of columns
        self.n = n

        self.data = [[0 for x in range(self.n)] for y in range(self.m)]

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        # i and j are integers and you don't need to check the type
        i = key.start  
        j = key.stop
        if isinstance(i, int) and isinstance(j, int):
            return self.data[i][j]
        elif isinstance(i, int) and j = :
            return "the row i"  # will implement it
        elif isinstance(j, int) and i = :
            return "the column j"  # will implement it
```

The `key` parameter will be a `slice` object if you call your instance with syntax like: `instance[1:10]`. But if you call your instance like: `instance[1]` the key value will be an integer with a value equal to 1.

In former case, you can get first parameter (in that example: 1) by calling `key.start` and you can get second parameter (in that example: 10) by calling `key.stop`.

So maybe it's better for you to check the type of the `key` parameter at the beggining of the method.